# Как фон хэдера(прозрачный) сделать поверх другого фона который относится к другой секции?

Tags: html, css, background, header, position

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]У меня фон шапки накладывается на другой фон, и  при этом при смене разрешений(мобилька-планш-вусктоп)шапка не должна съезжать... Я использую позишн абсолют, но возможно дело в том что позиционирую от окна браузера, поэтому съезжает.. Лио возможно как-то сделать без позиционирования... Но шапка должна быть поверх синего фона и при этом быть зафиксирована и не съезжать при смене разрешения.

```css
.body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Open Sans",Arial,sans-serif ;
    min-width: 280px;
}

.visually-hidden {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    clip-path: inset(100%);
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.page-header {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  outline: 3px solid darkorchid;
}

.page-header__wrapper {
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0 20px;
box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

}

.page-header__logo {
}

.page-header__logo-img {

}


.downloads {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 320px;
    outline: 3px solid goldenrod;

}
.downloads__background {
    height: 462px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.downloads__wrapper {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.downloads__title {
    display: block;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 28px;
}

.downloads__title {
    display: none;
}

.downloads__title--mobile {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

.downloads__buttons-block {
    background-color: #1D2631;
}

.downloads__list {
    margin: 0 -17.5px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.downloads__item {
    padding: 0 17.5px;
}


@media (min-width: 768px) {

    .downloads {
        width: 660px;
        position: relative;
        outline: 3px solid red;
    }
    .downloads__wrapper {
        padding: 0 20px;
    }

    .downloads__title--mobile {
        display: none;
    }

    .downloads__title--tablet {
        display: block;
    }

    .downloads__buttons-block {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        top: 150px;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: transparent;

    }
    .downloads__background {
        background-color: green;
    }

    .downloads__list {
        justify-content: flex-start;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {

    .downloads {
        width: 1200px;
        outline: 3px solid green;
    }

    .downloads__wrapper {
        padding: 0 130px;
    }
}
```

```html
OCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>header</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body class="page-body">
        <header class="page-header">
            <div class="page-header__wrapper">
                <p class="page-header__logo">
                    <span class="visually-hidden">PINK</span>
                    <svg class="page-header__logo-img" width="74" height="23" viewBox="0 0 74 23" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path d="M0.00496827 1.54857C0.00487772 1.21254 0.135804 0.889818 0.369742 0.649431C0.60368 0.409043 0.922049 0.27008 1.25676 0.262266H8.39001C13.4469 0.262266 16.7751 2.9645 16.7751 7.39179V7.45162C16.7751 12.2977 12.7415 14.8105 7.97274 14.8105H2.53836V21.611C2.55394 21.7874 2.53277 21.9651 2.47619 22.1329C2.41961 22.3006 2.32887 22.4547 2.20973 22.5854C2.09058 22.716 1.94565 22.8204 1.78416 22.8918C1.62266 22.9631 1.44812 23 1.27166 23C1.0952 23 0.920671 22.9631 0.759173 22.8918C0.597674 22.8204 0.452744 22.716 0.333602 22.5854C0.21446 22.4547 0.123708 22.3006 0.0671295 22.1329C0.0105515 21.9651 -0.0106138 21.7874 0.00496827 21.611V1.54857ZM8.07209 12.5171C11.7778 12.5171 14.2119 10.5228 14.2119 7.53139V7.47156C14.2119 4.26078 11.8175 2.59556 8.25092 2.59556H2.58804V12.4772L8.07209 12.5171Z" fill="white"/>
                        <path d="M21.5935 1.38904C21.5779 1.21262 21.5991 1.03487 21.6556 0.867114C21.7122 0.699353 21.803 0.545245 21.9221 0.414596C22.0412 0.283947 22.1862 0.179616 22.3477 0.108238C22.5092 0.0368607 22.6837 0 22.8602 0C23.0366 0 23.2112 0.0368607 23.3727 0.108238C23.5342 0.179616 23.6791 0.283947 23.7982 0.414596C23.9174 0.545245 24.0081 0.699353 24.0647 0.867114C24.1213 1.03487 24.1425 1.21262 24.1269 1.38904V21.611C24.1425 21.7874 24.1213 21.9651 24.0647 22.1329C24.0081 22.3006 23.9174 22.4548 23.7982 22.5854C23.6791 22.7161 23.5342 22.8204 23.3727 22.8918C23.2112 22.9631 23.0366 23 22.8602 23C22.6837 23 22.5092 22.9631 22.3477 22.8918C22.1862 22.8204 22.0412 22.7161 21.9221 22.5854C21.803 22.4548 21.7122 22.3006 21.6556 22.1329C21.5991 21.9651 21.5779 21.7874 21.5935 21.611V1.38904Z" fill="white"/>
                        <path d="M30.674 1.41895C30.6816 1.08908 30.8163 0.775007 31.0497 0.542621C31.2831 0.310235 31.597 0.177597 31.9258 0.172531H32.2735C32.5316 0.177833 32.7843 0.248188 33.0082 0.377127C33.2322 0.506065 33.4202 0.689448 33.5551 0.910412L47.1559 18.3104V1.35912C47.1559 1.0312 47.2857 0.7167 47.5168 0.484821C47.7478 0.252942 48.0611 0.122673 48.3879 0.122673C48.7146 0.122673 49.0279 0.252942 49.259 0.484821C49.49 0.7167 49.6198 1.0312 49.6198 1.35912V21.6508C49.6252 21.8051 49.5993 21.9589 49.5435 22.1028C49.4878 22.2467 49.4034 22.3777 49.2956 22.4878C49.1877 22.5979 49.0587 22.6848 48.9163 22.7432C48.7739 22.8016 48.6211 22.8303 48.4673 22.8275H48.3382C48.0744 22.8092 47.8184 22.7294 47.5908 22.5944C47.3631 22.4593 47.17 22.2728 47.0268 22.0497L33.1179 4.24085V21.6508C33.1158 21.9722 32.991 22.2805 32.7692 22.5124C32.5474 22.7442 32.2456 22.882 31.9258 22.8973C31.6008 22.892 31.291 22.7581 31.064 22.5246C30.8369 22.2911 30.711 21.9771 30.7137 21.6508V1.41895H30.674Z" fill="white"/>
                        <path d="M55.9384 1.38904C55.9228 1.21262 55.944 1.03487 56.0005 0.867114C56.0571 0.699353 56.1479 0.545245 56.267 0.414596C56.3862 0.283947 56.5311 0.179616 56.6926 0.108238C56.8541 0.0368607 57.0286 0 57.2051 0C57.3815 0 57.5561 0.0368607 57.7176 0.108238C57.8791 0.179616 58.024 0.283947 58.1431 0.414596C58.2623 0.545245 58.353 0.699353 58.4096 0.867114C58.4662 1.03487 58.4874 1.21262 58.4718 1.38904V13.6837L71.2282 0.551443C71.4899 0.279712 71.8455 0.119105 72.2216 0.10273C72.5468 0.115453 72.8548 0.252812 73.0821 0.486531C73.3094 0.72025 73.4388 1.03254 73.4436 1.35912C73.4366 1.52896 73.3961 1.69572 73.3245 1.84975C73.2529 2.00379 73.1516 2.14205 73.0264 2.25655L65.0785 10.1539L73.6523 20.6836C73.8764 20.9441 73.9998 21.2768 74 21.6209C73.9961 21.7933 73.9583 21.9633 73.8887 22.121C73.8191 22.2786 73.719 22.4209 73.5943 22.5395C73.4696 22.6582 73.3228 22.7509 73.1622 22.8123C73.0016 22.8737 72.8305 22.9026 72.6588 22.8973C72.4588 22.8891 72.2639 22.8322 72.0908 22.7314C71.9177 22.6306 71.7716 22.4891 71.6653 22.3189L63.3001 11.859L58.4718 16.7051V21.591C58.4718 21.7573 58.4391 21.922 58.3757 22.0756C58.3123 22.2293 58.2194 22.3689 58.1022 22.4865C57.9851 22.6041 57.846 22.6973 57.6929 22.761C57.5398 22.8246 57.3757 22.8574 57.21 22.8574C57.0443 22.8574 56.8803 22.8246 56.7272 22.761C56.5741 22.6973 56.435 22.6041 56.3179 22.4865C56.2007 22.3689 56.1078 22.2293 56.0443 22.0756C55.9809 21.922 55.9483 21.7573 55.9483 21.591V1.38904H55.9384Z" fill="white"/>
                    </svg>
                </p>
                <nav class="page-header__navigation">
                    <button class="page-header__toggle button" type="button" aria-label="Открыть меню">
                        <svg width="50" height="24" viewBox="0 0 50 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path d="M1.13659 0.00020839C0.986512 -0.00251551 0.837358 0.0214885 0.698091 0.0707781C0.558823 0.120068 0.432317 0.193625 0.326173 0.28703C0.22003 0.380436 0.136442 0.49176 0.0804303 0.614315C0.024419 0.73687 -0.00285856 0.868124 0.000236809 1.00019V3.00016C0.000236809 3.26537 0.119959 3.51972 0.333067 3.70725C0.546174 3.89478 0.83521 4.00014 1.13659 4.00014H48.8634C49.0135 4.00286 49.1626 3.97886 49.3019 3.92957C49.4412 3.88028 49.5677 3.80672 49.6738 3.71332C49.78 3.61991 49.8636 3.50859 49.9196 3.38603C49.9756 3.26348 50.0029 3.13222 49.9998 3.00016V1.00019C49.9998 0.734979 49.88 0.48063 49.6669 0.293097C49.4538 0.105563 49.1648 0.00020839 48.8634 0.00020839H1.13659ZM1.13659 10C0.986512 9.99731 0.837358 10.0213 0.698091 10.0706C0.558823 10.1199 0.432317 10.1935 0.326173 10.2869C0.22003 10.3803 0.136442 10.4916 0.0804303 10.6141C0.024419 10.7367 -0.00285856 10.868 0.000236809 11V13C0.000236809 13.2652 0.119959 13.5195 0.333067 13.7071C0.546174 13.8946 0.83521 14 1.13659 14H48.8634C49.0135 14.0027 49.1626 13.9787 49.3019 13.9294C49.4412 13.8801 49.5677 13.8065 49.6738 13.7131C49.78 13.6197 49.8636 13.5084 49.9196 13.3859C49.9756 13.2633 50.0029 13.132 49.9998 13V11C49.9998 10.7348 49.88 10.4805 49.6669 10.2929C49.4538 10.1054 49.1648 10 48.8634 10H1.13659ZM1.13659 19.9999C0.986512 19.9971 0.837358 20.0211 0.698091 20.0704C0.558823 20.1197 0.432317 20.1933 0.326173 20.2867C0.22003 20.3801 0.136442 20.4914 0.0804303 20.614C0.024419 20.7365 -0.00285856 20.8678 0.000236809 20.9998V22.9998C0.000236809 23.265 0.119959 23.5194 0.333067 23.7069C0.546174 23.8944 0.83521 23.9998 1.13659 23.9998H48.8634C49.0135 24.0025 49.1626 23.9785 49.3019 23.9292C49.4412 23.8799 49.5677 23.8064 49.6738 23.713C49.78 23.6196 49.8636 23.5082 49.9196 23.3857C49.9756 23.2631 50.0029 23.1319 49.9998 22.9998V20.9998C49.9998 20.7346 49.88 20.4803 49.6669 20.2927C49.4538 20.1052 49.1648 19.9999 48.8634 19.9999H1.13659Z" fill="white"/>
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="page-header__list-navigation visually-hidden">
                        <li class="page-header__item">
                            <a class="page-header__link" href="#">Главная</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="page-header__item">
                            <a class="page-header__link" href="#">Фотографии</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="page-header__item">
                            <a class="page-header__link" href="#">Конкурс</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="page-header__item">
                            <a class="page-header__link" href="#">html academy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
         <section class="downloads">
      <div class="downloads__background">
        <strong class="downloads__title downloads__title--mobile">Взгляните на жизнь иначе</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="downloads__wrapper">
        <h2 class="visually-hidden">Загрузка приложения на разные платформы</h2>
        <div class="downloads__buttons-block">
          <strong class="downloads__title downloads__title--tablet">Взгляните на жизнь иначе</strong>
          <a class="downloads__link" href="https://www.apple.com/iphone/">Скачать приложение</a>
          <ul class="downloads__list">
            <li class="downloads__item">
              <a class="downloads__link-apple" href="" aria-label="перейти в магазин Apple">
                <img class="downloads__img" src="apple-logo.png" alt="Логотип Apple" width="47" height="56">
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="downloads__item">
              <a class="downloads__link-google" href="" aria-label="перейти в Google play">
                <img class="downloads__img" src="android-logo.png" alt="Логотип Android">
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="downloads__item">
              <a class="downloads__link-microsoft" href="" aria-label="перейти в Microsoft store">
                <img class="downloads__img" src="microsoft-logo.png" alt="Логотип Microsoft">
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <p class="downloads__text">Доступно для iPhone, iPad, Android, Windows Phone, OS X, Windows 8</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без абсолютного можно, поместив `header` в `downloads__background`.
Но, если хотите и там с абсолютным позиционированием, то дайте `downloads__background` - `position: relative`, a `header` - `left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%)` - это отцентрирует блок `header` посередине

Comment: Вы конечно правы.. но тогда мне придётся переделывать разметку.. так как хэдэр будет внутри секшена.. а это не семантично

Comment: Надо было  не заморачиваться и сделать  хэдер, а внутри этот кусок с поверхностным фоном определить как хэдер-топ, а секцию с downloads  сделать хэдэр-боттом

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам нужно, чтобы шапка всегда была видна, то можно добавить `z-index` с большим значением:

```css
.body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Open Sans",Arial,sans-serif ;
    min-width: 280px;
}

.visually-hidden {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    clip-path: inset(100%);
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.page-header {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  outline: 3px solid darkorchid;
  z-index: 999;
}

.page-header__wrapper {
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0 20px;
box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

}

.page-header__logo {
}

.page-header__logo-img {

}


.downloads {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 320px;
    outline: 3px solid goldenrod;

}
.downloads__background {
    height: 462px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.downloads__wrapper {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.downloads__title {
    display: block;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 28px;
}

.downloads__title {
    display: none;
}

.downloads__title--mobile {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

.downloads__buttons-block {
    background-color: #1D2631;
}

.downloads__list {
    margin: 0 -17.5px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.downloads__item {
    padding: 0 17.5px;
}


@media (min-width: 768px) {

    .downloads {
        width: 660px;
        position: relative;
        outline: 3px solid red;
    }
    .downloads__wrapper {
        padding: 0 20px;
    }

    .downloads__title--mobile {
        display: none;
    }

    .downloads__title--tablet {
        display: block;
    }

    .downloads__buttons-block {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        top: 150px;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: transparent;

    }
    .downloads__background {
        background-color: green;
    }

    .downloads__list {
        justify-content: flex-start;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {

    .downloads {
        width: 1200px;
        outline: 3px solid green;
    }

    .downloads__wrapper {
        padding: 0 130px;
    }
}
```

```html
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>header</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body class="page-body">
        <header class="page-header">
            <div class="page-header__wrapper">
                <p class="page-header__logo">
                    <span class="visually-hidden">PINK</span>
                    <svg class="page-header__logo-img" width="74" height="23" viewBox="0 0 74 23" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path d="M0.00496827 1.54857C0.00487772 1.21254 0.135804 0.889818 0.369742 0.649431C0.60368 0.409043 0.922049 0.27008 1.25676 0.262266H8.39001C13.4469 0.262266 16.7751 2.9645 16.7751 7.39179V7.45162C16.7751 12.2977 12.7415 14.8105 7.97274 14.8105H2.53836V21.611C2.55394 21.7874 2.53277 21.9651 2.47619 22.1329C2.41961 22.3006 2.32887 22.4547 2.20973 22.5854C2.09058 22.716 1.94565 22.8204 1.78416 22.8918C1.62266 22.9631 1.44812 23 1.27166 23C1.0952 23 0.920671 22.9631 0.759173 22.8918C0.597674 22.8204 0.452744 22.716 0.333602 22.5854C0.21446 22.4547 0.123708 22.3006 0.0671295 22.1329C0.0105515 21.9651 -0.0106138 21.7874 0.00496827 21.611V1.54857ZM8.07209 12.5171C11.7778 12.5171 14.2119 10.5228 14.2119 7.53139V7.47156C14.2119 4.26078 11.8175 2.59556 8.25092 2.59556H2.58804V12.4772L8.07209 12.5171Z" fill="white"/>
                        <path d="M21.5935 1.38904C21.5779 1.21262 21.5991 1.03487 21.6556 0.867114C21.7122 0.699353 21.803 0.545245 21.9221 0.414596C22.0412 0.283947 22.1862 0.179616 22.3477 0.108238C22.5092 0.0368607 22.6837 0 22.8602 0C23.0366 0 23.2112 0.0368607 23.3727 0.108238C23.5342 0.179616 23.6791 0.283947 23.7982 0.414596C23.9174 0.545245 24.0081 0.699353 24.0647 0.867114C24.1213 1.03487 24.1425 1.21262 24.1269 1.38904V21.611C24.1425 21.7874 24.1213 21.9651 24.0647 22.1329C24.0081 22.3006 23.9174 22.4548 23.7982 22.5854C23.6791 22.7161 23.5342 22.8204 23.3727 22.8918C23.2112 22.9631 23.0366 23 22.8602 23C22.6837 23 22.5092 22.9631 22.3477 22.8918C22.1862 22.8204 22.0412 22.7161 21.9221 22.5854C21.803 22.4548 21.7122 22.3006 21.6556 22.1329C21.5991 21.9651 21.5779 21.7874 21.5935 21.611V1.38904Z" fill="white"/>
                        <path d="M30.674 1.41895C30.6816 1.08908 30.8163 0.775007 31.0497 0.542621C31.2831 0.310235 31.597 0.177597 31.9258 0.172531H32.2735C32.5316 0.177833 32.7843 0.248188 33.0082 0.377127C33.2322 0.506065 33.4202 0.689448 33.5551 0.910412L47.1559 18.3104V1.35912C47.1559 1.0312 47.2857 0.7167 47.5168 0.484821C47.7478 0.252942 48.0611 0.122673 48.3879 0.122673C48.7146 0.122673 49.0279 0.252942 49.259 0.484821C49.49 0.7167 49.6198 1.0312 49.6198 1.35912V21.6508C49.6252 21.8051 49.5993 21.9589 49.5435 22.1028C49.4878 22.2467 49.4034 22.3777 49.2956 22.4878C49.1877 22.5979 49.0587 22.6848 48.9163 22.7432C48.7739 22.8016 48.6211 22.8303 48.4673 22.8275H48.3382C48.0744 22.8092 47.8184 22.7294 47.5908 22.5944C47.3631 22.4593 47.17 22.2728 47.0268 22.0497L33.1179 4.24085V21.6508C33.1158 21.9722 32.991 22.2805 32.7692 22.5124C32.5474 22.7442 32.2456 22.882 31.9258 22.8973C31.6008 22.892 31.291 22.7581 31.064 22.5246C30.8369 22.2911 30.711 21.9771 30.7137 21.6508V1.41895H30.674Z" fill="white"/>
                        <path d="M55.9384 1.38904C55.9228 1.21262 55.944 1.03487 56.0005 0.867114C56.0571 0.699353 56.1479 0.545245 56.267 0.414596C56.3862 0.283947 56.5311 0.179616 56.6926 0.108238C56.8541 0.0368607 57.0286 0 57.2051 0C57.3815 0 57.5561 0.0368607 57.7176 0.108238C57.8791 0.179616 58.024 0.283947 58.1431 0.414596C58.2623 0.545245 58.353 0.699353 58.4096 0.867114C58.4662 1.03487 58.4874 1.21262 58.4718 1.38904V13.6837L71.2282 0.551443C71.4899 0.279712 71.8455 0.119105 72.2216 0.10273C72.5468 0.115453 72.8548 0.252812 73.0821 0.486531C73.3094 0.72025 73.4388 1.03254 73.4436 1.35912C73.4366 1.52896 73.3961 1.69572 73.3245 1.84975C73.2529 2.00379 73.1516 2.14205 73.0264 2.25655L65.0785 10.1539L73.6523 20.6836C73.8764 20.9441 73.9998 21.2768 74 21.6209C73.9961 21.7933 73.9583 21.9633 73.8887 22.121C73.8191 22.2786 73.719 22.4209 73.5943 22.5395C73.4696 22.6582 73.3228 22.7509 73.1622 22.8123C73.0016 22.8737 72.8305 22.9026 72.6588 22.8973C72.4588 22.8891 72.2639 22.8322 72.0908 22.7314C71.9177 22.6306 71.7716 22.4891 71.6653 22.3189L63.3001 11.859L58.4718 16.7051V21.591C58.4718 21.7573 58.4391 21.922 58.3757 22.0756C58.3123 22.2293 58.2194 22.3689 58.1022 22.4865C57.9851 22.6041 57.846 22.6973 57.6929 22.761C57.5398 22.8246 57.3757 22.8574 57.21 22.8574C57.0443 22.8574 56.8803 22.8246 56.7272 22.761C56.5741 22.6973 56.435 22.6041 56.3179 22.4865C56.2007 22.3689 56.1078 22.2293 56.0443 22.0756C55.9809 21.922 55.9483 21.7573 55.9483 21.591V1.38904H55.9384Z" fill="white"/>
                    </svg>
                </p>
                <nav class="page-header__navigation">
                    <button class="page-header__toggle button" type="button" aria-label="Открыть меню">
                        <svg width="50" height="24" viewBox="0 0 50 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path d="M1.13659 0.00020839C0.986512 -0.00251551 0.837358 0.0214885 0.698091 0.0707781C0.558823 0.120068 0.432317 0.193625 0.326173 0.28703C0.22003 0.380436 0.136442 0.49176 0.0804303 0.614315C0.024419 0.73687 -0.00285856 0.868124 0.000236809 1.00019V3.00016C0.000236809 3.26537 0.119959 3.51972 0.333067 3.70725C0.546174 3.89478 0.83521 4.00014 1.13659 4.00014H48.8634C49.0135 4.00286 49.1626 3.97886 49.3019 3.92957C49.4412 3.88028 49.5677 3.80672 49.6738 3.71332C49.78 3.61991 49.8636 3.50859 49.9196 3.38603C49.9756 3.26348 50.0029 3.13222 49.9998 3.00016V1.00019C49.9998 0.734979 49.88 0.48063 49.6669 0.293097C49.4538 0.105563 49.1648 0.00020839 48.8634 0.00020839H1.13659ZM1.13659 10C0.986512 9.99731 0.837358 10.0213 0.698091 10.0706C0.558823 10.1199 0.432317 10.1935 0.326173 10.2869C0.22003 10.3803 0.136442 10.4916 0.0804303 10.6141C0.024419 10.7367 -0.00285856 10.868 0.000236809 11V13C0.000236809 13.2652 0.119959 13.5195 0.333067 13.7071C0.546174 13.8946 0.83521 14 1.13659 14H48.8634C49.0135 14.0027 49.1626 13.9787 49.3019 13.9294C49.4412 13.8801 49.5677 13.8065 49.6738 13.7131C49.78 13.6197 49.8636 13.5084 49.9196 13.3859C49.9756 13.2633 50.0029 13.132 49.9998 13V11C49.9998 10.7348 49.88 10.4805 49.6669 10.2929C49.4538 10.1054 49.1648 10 48.8634 10H1.13659ZM1.13659 19.9999C0.986512 19.9971 0.837358 20.0211 0.698091 20.0704C0.558823 20.1197 0.432317 20.1933 0.326173 20.2867C0.22003 20.3801 0.136442 20.4914 0.0804303 20.614C0.024419 20.7365 -0.00285856 20.8678 0.000236809 20.9998V22.9998C0.000236809 23.265 0.119959 23.5194 0.333067 23.7069C0.546174 23.8944 0.83521 23.9998 1.13659 23.9998H48.8634C49.0135 24.0025 49.1626 23.9785 49.3019 23.9292C49.4412 23.8799 49.5677 23.8064 49.6738 23.713C49.78 23.6196 49.8636 23.5082 49.9196 23.3857C49.9756 23.2631 50.0029 23.1319 49.9998 22.9998V20.9998C49.9998 20.7346 49.88 20.4803 49.6669 20.2927C49.4538 20.1052 49.1648 19.9999 48.8634 19.9999H1.13659Z" fill="white"/>
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="page-header__list-navigation visually-hidden">
                        <li class="page-header__item">
                            <a class="page-header__link" href="#">Главная</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="page-header__item">
                            <a class="page-header__link" href="#">Фотографии</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="page-header__item">
                            <a class="page-header__link" href="#">Конкурс</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="page-header__item">
                            <a class="page-header__link" href="#">html academy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
         <section class="downloads">
      <div class="downloads__background">
        <strong class="downloads__title downloads__title--mobile">Взгляните на жизнь иначе</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="downloads__wrapper">
        <h2 class="visually-hidden">Загрузка приложения на разные платформы</h2>
        <div class="downloads__buttons-block">
          <strong class="downloads__title downloads__title--tablet">Взгляните на жизнь иначе</strong>
          <a class="downloads__link" href="https://www.apple.com/iphone/">Скачать приложение</a>
          <ul class="downloads__list">
            <li class="downloads__item">
              <a class="downloads__link-apple" href="" aria-label="перейти в магазин Apple">
                <img class="downloads__img" src="apple-logo.png" alt="Логотип Apple" width="47" height="56">
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="downloads__item">
              <a class="downloads__link-google" href="" aria-label="перейти в Google play">
                <img class="downloads__img" src="android-logo.png" alt="Логотип Android">
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="downloads__item">
              <a class="downloads__link-microsoft" href="" aria-label="перейти в Microsoft store">
                <img class="downloads__img" src="microsoft-logo.png" alt="Логотип Microsoft">
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <p class="downloads__text">Доступно для iPhone, iPad, Android, Windows Phone, OS X, Windows 8</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    </body>
</html>
```